# Bootstrap 4 align right in cell

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-lists

I'm currently writing an interface for a ticket system that uses Bootstrap 4's grid system to position components about the system. As you can see from the screenshot below, the UI has two container-fluid divs stacked. The top div aligns perfectly, the second one I am struggling with.

I want it to render like this (without the pink - the pink is showing the two cols):

[image: how I would like to render]

however it is rendering like this:

[image: how it is currently rendering]

The code that renders this is as follows:

HTML:

```html
<div class="container-fluid container-navbar">
    <div class="row navbar">
        <div class="col">
            logo goes here
        </div>
        <div class="col text-center help-desk">
            help desk.
        </div>
        <div class="col text-right">
            <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-bars" id="settings-menu" ></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row ticket-summary-navbar">
    <div class="col text-right">
      <div class="global-ticket-summary">
        <ul>
          <li >
            <p class="ticketCount" >5</p>
            <p class="nameLabel" >User1</p>
          </li>
          <li >
            <p class="ticketCount" >3</p>
            <p class="nameLabel" >User2</p>
          </li>
          <li >
            <p class="ticketCount" >8</p>
            <p class="nameLabel" >User3</p>
          </li>
          <li >
            <p class="ticketCount" >6</p>
            <p class="nameLabel" >User4</p>
          </li>
          <li >
            <p class="ticketCount" >2</p>
            <p class="nameLabel" >User5</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
body{
    background-color: #ababab;
}

.navbar{
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(58, 191, 195, 1);
    height: 75px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.container-navbar{
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    min-width: 490px;
}

.help-desk{
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}

#settings-menu{
    font-size: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.ticket-summary-navbar{
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    height: 90px;
}

.global-ticket-summary {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color: #1b1b1b;
    font-weight: 200;
}

.global-ticket-summary ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.global-ticket-summary ul li {
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
}

.global-ticket-summary ul li .ticketCount {
    font-size: 22pt;
    margin-bottom: -4px;
    cursor: pointer !important;
}

.global-ticket-summary ul li .nameLabel {
    font-size: 11pt;
    /*margin-bottom: 0;*/
    color: #656565;
    cursor: pointer !important;
}
```

As you can see it renders the <ul> in the middle, even though I have the text-right directive.

I can certainly get it working by adding "float:right;" to the UL - which positions correctly horizontally, however it then no longer aligns vertically correctly (it snaps to the top of the div). I have searched in many places for a solution, however all point to using the navbar for Bootstrap, which isn't relevant in this case.

Is there a way I can have the UL align right to its parent div without resorting to padding/margin CSS hacks?

Plunkr link also: https://next.plnkr.co/plunk/y4EYmtpgwRvHkjuI

Answer (score 0):

Put the text align on the global-ticket-summary div, and if that doesn't work put it in the UL. Text align only works for the direct child elements I believe

Comment: Thanks for your response - i've tried both and they have not worked. Thank you any way.

Comment: have you inspected your global-ticket-summary and ul elements to see if they have enough width? it looks like you have hard coded it to 100px, maybe there isn't enough room to actually do a text-right align

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox to align content. Just put this .flex-container class into your code to right align child elements.

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}
```

If you are new to css i will recommend you to take a look into flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

You want to put ul in right side of col. Correct me! if i misunderstood your question.
So, you need to do the following in your style.css file, 
just replace with following css code.

```
.global-ticket-summary ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: right!important;
}

.global-ticket-summary ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use flex utilities for bootstrap 4. Add following classes to the first column (which is having text-right):  **d-flex, justify-content-end**.

```
...
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row ticket-summary-navbar">
        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-end">
...
```

It is aligning as you want to the right.

For reference here is link to flex utility for bootstrap 4 : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

Comment: thanks however this did the same thing as the float: right; it aligned it right however it was no longer vertically aligned to the center

Comment: To vertically align it to center just add align-items-center class to the column along with d-flex and justify-content-end. It will align all items to center vertically. Let me know if this resolves the issue.